# Jackson deserializer: deserialize object with access to fields in outer scope?

Tags: java, jackson

I have this class

```java
class ExampleModel {
   Foo fooField;
   Bar barField;
}

class Bar {
   String name;
}
```

I need to refactor to move `fooField` to under `barField` so the new class structures look like

```java
class ExampleModel {
   Bar barField;
}

class Bar {
   String name;
   Foo fooField;
}
```

I now have JSON files that were serialized from the old class structure, where fooField was outside the Bar class. How can I write a deserializer for these JSON files so that they are mapped to the new class structure, i.e. fooField now inside the Bar class?

I can write a Deserializer that applies to the whole `ExampleModel` class but this is not something I want. The reason is I have to write the deserialize operations for all other fields in the `ExampleModel` class without being able to use the Jackson deserialize support.

My question is:

Can I write a deserializer for just the `Bar` class that can know how to copy the `fooField` from the outer scope to inside the `Bar`?